# Getting error when trying to delete record from hasMany collection

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

```
ember-data@2.5.3
ember@2.4.3
```

I am getting the following error `"Cannot set property 'jqXHR' of undefined"` when attempting to delete a record.  The item has already been deleted via `model.deleteRecord`, I am now trying to persist it to the server.  I have tried this with both `item.save()` and `item.destroyRecord()` any ideas of what this message means?  The request never actually reaches the server.

[image]

Comment: Have discovered that this is caused by `ember-data-has-many-query`, will update with a solution once resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by a bug in `v0.1.0` of the `ember-data-has-many-query` addon, which was fixed in `v0.1.1`. Updating to the latest version should fix it.